# Newbie programmer trying to set up zookeeper

Tags: java, apache, sockets, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to set up a zookeeper cluster of three servers but I'm not quite sure what I'm doing.  I have the same config file on each machine.  It looks like this:

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/home/scix3/zookeeper/data
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
autopurge.purgeInterval=24
autopurge.snapRetainCount=5
server.1=192.168.2.106:2888:3888
server.2=192.168.2.102:2888:3888
server.3=192.168.2.105:2888:3888
```

I have a myid file in the dataDir and it corresponds with the server number in the zoo.cfg file.  I know that zookeeper is running on each system because when i command $ bin/zkServer.sh the following is outputted:

```
Starting zookeeper ... already running as process 9548.
```

However, when I run bin/zkCli.sh on any of the computers i get the following message.

```
    scix3@M6:~/zookeeper$ bin/zkCli.sh
    Connecting to localhost:2181
    2015-06-02 14:29:57,310 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.6-1569965, built on 02/20/2014 09:09 GMT
    2015-06-02 14:29:57,313 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:host.name=M6
    2015-06-02 14:29:57,313 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_79
    2015-06-02 14:29:57,316 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    2015-06-02 14:29:57,316 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
    2015-06-02 14:29:57,316 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.class.path=/home/scix3/zookeeper/bin/../build/classes:/home/scix3/zookeeper/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/home/scix3/zookeeper/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/home/scix3/zookeeper/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/home/scix3/zookeeper/bin/../lib/netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:/home/scix3/zookeeper/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/home/scix3/zookeeper/bin/../lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/home/scix3/zookeeper/bin/../zookeeper- 3.4.6.jar:/home/scix3/zookeeper/bin/../src/java/lib/*.jar:/home/scix3/zookeeper/bi n/../conf:
    2015-06-02 14:29:57,316 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client            environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
    2015-06-02 14:29:57,316 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client     environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
    2015-06-02 14:29:57,316 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client  environment:java.compiler=<NA>
    2015-06-02 14:29:57,316 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:os.name=Linux
    2015-06-02 14:29:57,316 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:os.arch=amd64
    2015-06-02 14:29:57,316 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:os.version=3.13.0-45-generic
    2015-06-02 14:29:57,317 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:user.name=scix3
    2015-06-02 14:29:57,317 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:user.home=/home/scix3
    2015-06-02 14:29:57,317 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:user.dir=/home/scix3/zookeeper
    2015-06-02 14:29:57,318 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeper@438] - Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=30000 watcher=org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain$MyWatcher@2e559e7f
    Welcome to ZooKeeper!
    2015-06-02 14:29:57,344 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@975] - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
    JLine support is enabled
    2015-06-02 14:29:57,352 [myid:] - INFO  [main-  SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@852] - Socket connection  established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
    2015-06-02 14:29:57,356 [myid:] - INFO  [main- SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1098] - Unable to read additional  data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
    [zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTING) 0] 2015-06-02 14:29:59,140 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@975] - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
    2015-06-02 14:29:59,140 [myid:] - INFO  [main-   SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@852] - Socket connection  established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
    2015-06-02 14:29:59,141 [myid:] - INFO  [main-  SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1098] - Unable to read additional  data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket, closing socket  connection and attempting reconnect
```

Really, I'm just struggling to decipher the message that is being outputted, figure out how to make a single machine the master, connect the entire system, and implement it with apache storm.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: What specific command are you using to run zkCli? It looks like zkCli is trying to connect to localhost, but the ZK servers are bound to private IP addresses. You should be able to just specify the -server option to ensure zkCli connects to the correct host.

Comment: I've tried a multitude of commands including  `zkCli.shserver XXX.XXX.X.XXX` and the following message is repeated as if stuck in a loop: `[main-SendThread(192.168.2.106:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@852] - Socket connection established to 192.168.2.106/192.168.2.106:2181, initiating session` [main-SendThread(192.168.2.106:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1098] - Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect`  It's trying to connect but simply can't make the connection.

Comment: Additionally when I run `java -cp zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:conf / org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain zoo.cfg' i get the following error: `Error: Could not find or load main class .` which seems a little odd.  At this point i don't even know how i would test to see if there was a connection between all three of my servers. @kuujo

Comment: Try "telnet localhost 2181" and use some of the four-letter word commands (particularly "ruok" and "stat") to check the status of the node/cluster. When using zkCli.sh, are you able to enter any command such as "ls" and what response do you get back?

Comment: When I use that command i get connected and this message `Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.`  However, when i try a command like `ruok` or `stat` i get the following message: `imokConnection closed by foreign host.`  When i run `zkCli.sh` i am getting a message that says i am getting the following repeated message that continues (like an infinite loop).  I'm putting the message in the following text box.

Comment: `2015-06-03 10:34:17,989 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@975] - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)` `2015-06-03 10:34:17,989 [myid:] - INFO  [main SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@852] - Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session`  
(continued in next text box)

Comment: `2015-06-03 10:34:17,990 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1098] - Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
`

Comment: did you solve the problem or not ? i'm facing same issue !